# Debugging Office interop assemblies: how to get rid of automatic add-in disable?

Tags: office-interop

I know this is not particularly programming related, but some of you here may know the solution.

I have a project using Excel interop in C#, and C++/CLI wrappers for ugly C++ code, all in the same project. I can debug the whole code nicely by attaching the debugger to Excel.

Now, each time I stop debugging (for whatever reason), Excel hard disables my addin. I must open a fresh excel, do 15 clicks to reenable it to start a new debugging session.

I must add that Excel loading times are pretty high, since we use another team's huge XLL (necessary to run my addin).

This behavior is pretty annoying, I'd like to disable automatic disabling of add ins. Does someone knows how to do ? I have no objection to programmatically set/unset registry keys.